# Disable USB device: USB2.0-CRW (Generic)

Tags: card-reader

I have a problem with card reader in my notebook with Ubuntu 12.10. It's usage is always at 100% and powertop shows it's power consumption as 16W or even more (which is really really way too much for a card reader). This is the line from the powertop:

`16.7 W    100.0%        USB device: USB2.0-CRW (Generic)`

How can I reduce wakeups or disable this card reader? (I don't use the card reader very much)

Comment: First you need to figure out what drivers it's using; hunt through `/sys`.

Comment: I'm not sure what to search for, but I found out that it is realtek rts5139 card reader (I found it in /sys/usb/drivers)

Comment: I'm also having the same issue any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, card reader was consuming highest power. here what i did.

```
:find the card reader
lsusb
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller


:search the kernel module(replace rts with your card name/id)
lsmod | grep rts 

rtsx_usb_ms            20480  0
memstick               16384  1 rtsx_usb_ms
rtsx_usb_sdmmc         28672  0
rtsx_usb               20480  2 rtsx_usb_sdmmc,rtsx_usb_ms


:remove module with dependancies
rmmod rtsx_usb_ms
rmmod rtsx_usb_sdmmc
rmmod rtsx_usb
```

if things good you can blacklist module permenantly